# Return the IDs of a matrix that has all elemets of a vector

Tags: r

I know the answer is completely easy but I could not get it so far. Also I tried to find the answer through the similar questions but i could not. Anyway, I need to return the `ID` of matrix `m` that has all elemets of a vector (`NoN`). In the example that I prepared at below, I need to return IDs 1 and 3.

**Example:**

```
m<-matrix(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,34,45,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,3,3,3,3,21,22,3425,345,65,22,42,65,86,456,454,5678,5,234,22,65,21,22,786),nrow=19)
colnames(m)<-c("ID","LO")
NoN<-c(21,22)
```

**My attempts so far are as follow:**

```
1: m[all(m[,2] %in% NoN),1]
2: m[match(NoN, m[,2]),1]
3: subset(m, m[,2] %in% NoN)
4: m[which(m[,2] %in% NoN),1]
```

Appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took this answer from @**docendo discimus**, which I found it efficient and concise.

```
df <- as.data.frame(m); 
unique(df[as.logical(ave(df$LO, df$ID, FUN = function(x) all(NoN %in% x))),"ID"])
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function using base `R`:

```
FOO <- function(m, NoN){
  # split matrix based on ID column
  m2 <- lapply(split(m, m[, 1]), function(x) matrix(x, ncol = 2)) 
  # match every element of NoN, create logical matrix
  matchresult <- do.call(cbind, lapply(lapply(m2, function(x) lapply(NoN, function(y) match(y, x[,2]))), unlist))
  # print colnames (= ID) of columns with no NA
  as.numeric(colnames(matchresult)[colSums(apply(matchresult, 2, is.na)) == 0])
}
```

Result of function call:

```
> FOO(m, NoN)
[1] 1 3
```

Untested except for your example, but this should be able to handle any length of `NoN` as well as duplicated combinations of `ID` and `LO`.

---

Edit: More concise and efficient variant provided by @docendodiscimus:

```
FOO <- function(m, NoN){
  df <- as.data.frame(m) 
  unique(df[as.logical(ave(df$LO, df$ID, FUN = function(x) all(NoN %in% x))),"ID"])
}
```

Comment: In base R, I'd go for `df <- as.data.frame(m); unique(df[as.logical(ave(df$LO, df$ID, FUN = function(x) all(NoN %in% x))),"ID"])`

Comment: Thanks @LAP. I liked this answer more than the rest but you need to add 
"IDs <- as.numeric(IDs)
return(IDs)"
to your function

Comment: @EsterSilva, you could just wrap an `as.numeric()` around the third row (`colnames(...`).

Comment: @docendodiscimus, that is a great answer!

Comment: Thanks, you can add it to your answer if you like

Answer (score 2):

#### A not so safe way using base R:

```
m<-matrix(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,34,45,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,3,3,3,3,21,22,3425,345,65,22,42,65,86,456,454,5678,5,234,22,65,21,22,786),nrow=19)
colnames(m)<-c("ID","LO")
NoN<-c(21,22)

IDs <- m[m[, 2] %in% NoN, 1]
IDs <- table(IDs)

IDs <- names(IDs)[IDs >= length(NoN)]

> IDs
[1] "1" "3"
```

But beware, this does not take duplicated values into account. So if ID 1 would have two LOs of value 21 but no 22, it would still return ID 1.

#### EDIT: A safe way using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

m <- data.frame(m)

IDs <- m %>% 
  slice(which(LO %in% NoN)) %>%             # get all rows which contain values from NoN
  group_by(ID) %>%                          # group by ID
  summarise(uniques = n_distinct(LO)) %>%   # count unique values per ID
  filter(uniques == length(NoN)) %>%        # number of unique values has to be the same as the number of values in NoN
  select(ID) %>%                            # select ID columns
  unlist() %>%                              # unlist it
  as.numeric()                              # convert from named num to numeric

> IDs
[1] 1 3
```

Comment: Thanks @brettljausn. I already thought about something similar. It is working but I want to have a solution which is more efficient.

Comment: This is not a safe way to do it since any ID could occure multiple times with the same "LO" value.

Comment: I'm aware of this, I also warned of it in my answer. I've worked out a safe way, but I used dplyr and a data frame for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution that saves matrix `m` as a dataframe and performs a process for each `ID`:

```
# example data
m<-matrix(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,34,45,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,3,3,3,3,21,22,3425,345,65,22,42,65,86,456,454,5678,5,234,22,65,21,22,786),nrow=19)
colnames(m)<-c("ID","LO")
NoN<-c(21,22)

library(dplyr)

data.frame(m) %>%                            # save m as dataframe
  group_by(ID) %>%                           # for each ID
  summarise(sum_flag = sum(LO %in% NoN)) %>% # count number of LO elements in NoN
  filter(sum_flag == length(NoN)) %>%        # keep rows where this number matches the length of NoN
  pull(ID)                                   # get the corresponding IDs

# [1] 1 3
```

Keep in mind that this process assumes (based on your example) that elements of `NoN` and rows of `m` are unique.

Comment: If they're gonna use dplyr, I'd go for `data.frame(m) %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(all(NoN %in% LO)) %>% pull(ID) %>% unique`

Comment: Didn't think of the `all` function! I had in mind something similar at first (using `filter(sum(LO %in% NoN) == length(NoN))`), but for some reason I used `summarise` and then `filter`. I guess it better matched they way I had the process in my head :-) Any practical reasons? Is this going to be faster?

Comment: The `filter(sum(LO %in% NoN) == length(NoN))` part is once again not very robust if you can have duplicate entries.

Comment: Agree. That's why I mentioned uniqueness of both `NoN` elements and `m` rows at the end of my answer. I guess I'd have an additional process that keeps unique elements of `NoN` and rows of `m` before applying that. However, it's always better to post the (most) general solution, so I'll update my answer.